# Redirect form out of modal window after submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form within a Colorbox Modal window which successfully submits using the _submit handler. I then successfully redirect the form to another page (which pre-loads a few fields on another form) using `drupal_goto()`. The problem I am having is that redirect stays in the Colorbox Modal window. I need to somehow close the modal window and transfer the url of the new form to the parent window. I can get this to work with a jquery function of

```
$(#my_form_id).submit(function (){
   parent.window.location="/user/register";
});
```

The problem with this issue is that the function calls when my form is submitted while disregarding anything that happens in the submission handler. So what ends up happening is I get the new page/form without the pre-loaded values until I refresh the page.

Do you have any thought or idea?

Comment: While it is not related to the question - i strongly advice NOT use drupal_goto() in form submit handlers. Use $form_state['redirect'] instead http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using #ajax to submit the form and then allow the response to close the modal and go somewhere else. For example, here's a submit button that runs a function on click instead of submitting the form and reloading the page:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="super-cool-wrapper"></div>',
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => 'Submit',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'my_super_cool_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'super-cool-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
);
```

And then in your callback function:

```
function my_super_cool_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // Do what you normally would with the form submission.
  return '<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.window.location="some/where";
  </script>';
}
```

Now you can process the form as needed and return a response that simply redirects the user.

Comment: mm thanks I will have to try this out and see if that gets the desired result. I was thinking of doing something similar to this

Answer (score 0):

[Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) have nice tools for such thinks, when you read the help file (after installing [Advanced help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help), you can acheive this (and more :) out of the box.

very simple example code for the menu callback that prints the modal :

```
function mymodule_showmodal($js) {
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_include('ajax');

$form_state = array(
    'ajax' => true,
  );
$commands = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('modform',$form_state);
if ($form_state['executed']) {
  $commands = array(ctools_modal_command_dismiss());
}
print ajax_render($commands);
exit();
}
```

dont forget to put ['rebuild'] = true somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, here's how I got around it.

First I add a trigger in the $GLOBAL array like this:

```
function my_module_node_presave($node){
  if ($node->type == 'product'){
    $GLOBALS['redirect_parent'] = 'product_list';
  }
}
```

Then I add this nice event which gets triggered after the node has been saved

```
function my_module_drupal_goto_alter(){
  if (@$GLOBALS['redirect_parent']!=''){
    die('<script type="text/javascript">parent.window.location="/'.$GLOBALS['redirect_parent'].'";</script>');
    $GLOBALS['redirect_parent']='';
  }
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar problem with drual modal form. After user registration and forgot password I have to send it on thanks page.
Create tpl file and make registration link using below code.

```
<?php
echo l('Sign up here', 'user/register', array('query'=>array('destination'=>'thanks')));
?>
```

Create tpl file and make forgot password link using below code.

```
<?php
print l('Forgot Your Password?', 'user/password', array('query'=>array('destination'=>'thanks')));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

for redirecting you can pass inside

```
function() {
  window.location.replace ="url";
}
```